# system() call doesn't display in Arduino IDE Serial Monitor

Tags: c, arduino

I have the following code:

```
void setup() {
    // Configure the serial communication line at 9600 baud (bits per second.)
    Serial.begin(9600);
    delay(1000);
    system("ifconfig -a > /dev/ttyGSO");

    // Configure the button's pin for input signals.
    pinMode(pinButton, INPUT);
    // Configure the LED's pin for output.
    pinMode(pinLed, OUTPUT);
    // Configure the angle sensor's pin for input.
    pinMode(pinPotent, INPUT);
    // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
    lcd.begin(16, 2);

    lcd.setRGB(colorR, colorG, colorB);

    score = 5;
    angle = analogRead(pinPotent);
}
```

The `system("ifconfig -a > /dev/ttyGSO")` call doesn't print to the Arduino IDE's serial monitor. However if I enter `ifconfig -a > /dev/ttyGSO` directly into the serial terminal, it will print to the monitor as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical bug one might spend hours to find!

There is a  typo in this line:

```
system("ifconfig -a > /dev/ttyGSO");
```

The tty device should terminate with **zero** instead of the letter `O`:

```
system("ifconfig -a > /dev/ttyGS0");
```

Comment: Damn it... Thanks. I appreciate it.